# show two models in a Backbone view?

Tags: backbone.js, view, model

I have a photo gallery, and want to show 2 pages at once (like an opened book)

Each page is an entity (a model in backbone)

How do I associate a view to hold two model instances in backbone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the data to your template and use it:

```
var m1 = new Model1();
var m2 = new Model2();
var tpl = _.template( yourTemplate, {"model1":m1.toJSON(), "model2":m2.toJSON()} );
```

In the template you can access the data with:

```
<%= model1.value1 %>
<%= model2.value1 %>
```